# How can I add WSSE Header to my Web Service Client?

Tags: web-services, header, ws-security, soapheader

I want to add wsse Security header to my web service client on ASP 3.5. I test the web service from SoapUI using this Soap Envelope and get an answer:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:comp="http://myCompany.org.tr">   <soapenv:Header xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
 <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
 <wsse:UsernameToken xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd"/>
 <wsse:Username>MyUsername</wsse:Username>
 </wsse:Security>
</soapenv:Header>
<soapenv:Body>
    (Body Info.)

   </soapenv:Body>

</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I want to create this envelope through classic Web Service Reference which created by Visual Studi 2012. Which class should I use to add Username Info to my envelope?

Comment: You must add it manually through custom SOAP header or custom SOAP extension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you John, and Ladislav.

Turns out that you should add the header via web.config file to get properly ordered SOAP message. Otherwise .Net tries to nest your code with its own capsulation (even you dont ask for it), and sends some rubbish as a result.

Comment: Marking your own answer as correct just seems wrong.